# Wordpress error when installing parent theme

Tags: wordpress, windows, server, themes, mamp

I'm new to web dev: trying to install a custom theme to Wordpress. Running Windows 10 and working on a local server with MAMP.

**When I went to see my theme, I get the following message:**

```
Broken Themes
The following themes are installed but incomplete.

Name        Description
mywebsite   The parent theme is missing. Please install the "mywebsite;" parent theme.
```

**Error I get when trying to install:**

```
An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this 
server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support
forums.
```

Does anyone know how I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to upload my own custom theme. I have created a new folder in the themes directory and added an index.php, style.css and my own custom css for index.php file.

Comment: Please provide the code

Answer (score 0):

check if in your theme-child style.css has:

```
/*
    Theme Name: yourtheme-child
    Template: yourtheme
    Text Domain: yourtheme-child
*/
```

and in theme style.css:

```
/*
    Theme Name: yourtheme
*/
```

Comment: Hmm it says 'the parent theme could not be found.' To clarify - in my custom theme folder, I only have 3 files - 1 index.php, 1 style.css with the comments on it, and 1 actual css file.